# Do you get different powers by being good or evil?

Tags: infamous

I'm new to the game and am not sure which way to align myself.  What happens differently in the game if I'm evil than if I'm good?  Any information will be helpful.

Comment: I just wanted a simple title because it only needs a simple answer

Comment: The problem was your title was subjective. What does "better" mean?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry my English isn't up to your standards.

Comment: It's not an issue of the quality of your grammar.  It's simply a matter of search engine optimization; clearly stated questions are easier to find when searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few differences in your available powers depending on how you play. You can find them listed in [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/942025-infamous/faqs/56738), section [bc03].

Most of your core powers  will be more or less the same, but the upgrades you can unlock for them have different karmatic requirements. From the FAQ:

> Buying upgrades for powers requires you have the necessary XP, as well
>   as the karmic rank for it. For example, Shockwave Upgrade 2 asks for
>   1800 XP, but you also need to be Champion (Good) or Outlaw (Evil) rank
>   in your Karma to get it.

There are two powers unique to each playstyle, which you unlock by completing good or evil side-missions. Look for **[Overload Burst]** and **[Arc Lightning]** in the FAQ.

Generally speaking, being evil makes you more of a damage dealer (mainly due to increased splash damage with many of your powers), while being good allows you more precise control of what it is that you damage.

Comment: Plus being good replenishes your energy and sometimes heals you with your basic attacks sometimes and can restrain enemies with shock grenades, letting you use Karmic Overload sooner.

Comment: Thank you that's all I needed to know. :) more detail than I expected too haha.